# It's $\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^5-1)$ an integral extension?

Tags: commutative-algebra

It's $\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^5-1)$ an integral extension?

$\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^5-1) \simeq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ where $x^5-1=0$.

So is an integral extension because $x$ is integral  over $\mathbb{Z}$. It's right?

Comment: Hint: use the fact if $A \subset B$ is a ring extension, where $A$ and $B$ are commutative rings with 1, then the set of elements in $B$ which are integral over $A$ forms a subring of $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^5-1)$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module and so the extension is integral.

This uses the characterization:

> If $A \subseteq B$ are rings and $b \in B$, then $b$ is integral over $A$ iff $A[b]$ is a finitely generated $A$-module.

combined with this fact:

> Every submodule of a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-module is finitely generated.

Here is a concrete argument:

Take $b \in B=\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^5-1)=\mathbb{Z}[u]$. Write the matrix of the map $\mu: t \mapsto bt$ with respect to the basis $1,u,u^2,u^3,u^4$. Then $b$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of $\mu$, which is monic and has integers coefficients. Therefore, $b$ is integral.

Comment: There exists an intuitive argument?

Comment: @PregatireMatematica, see my edited answer.